# Grabbing a return of an Asynchronous request when it finishes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an asynchronous request that fires off to another web page to do some processing The code is below.  I'm having some issues with this. I want the request to be fired off, then ignored till its done, then when it finishes, I want to fire off an email.

It appears that the callback is never firing. What am I missing?

```
private HttpWebRequest req = null;
private IAsyncResult result = null;

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder pageUrl = "http://myurl.example.com";

    // Initialize web request
    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}", pageUrl.ToString()));
    req.Method = "GET";

    // Start the asynchronous request.
    try
    {
        result = (IAsyncResult)req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //lblProcess.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}


protected void RespCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    using (WebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(ar))
    {
        //using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) {
        //    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //}

    //function that just sends an email
        SendBatchEmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: the sendBatchEmail never gets called.

Comment: edited it, just meant to say asychronous web request

Comment: you might be having an exception. The error is thrown when you call EndXXXX method. Catch the exception in RespCallback and see whats wrong.

Comment: okay I will try that, though even when I run in DEBUG mode with a breakpoint on the callback, it never gets fired.

Comment: This isn't really appropriate logic for a web server. They don't really do fire and forget. They operate in the context of an HTTP request and response cycle. If this processing is short, you can do this all synchronously. If it takes too long then you should execute this code in the background, preferably using a separate application to do so.